# Django - Migrating data inside tables for smooth release

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dev-to-production

I am using Django Rest Framework for backend development, where I have set up 2 environments. I have split settings files as required and both the environments have different DBs which are working fine, I am using Zappa(AWS lambda) for deploys, I was wondering is there an elegant way of migrating data(not models but data inside models say a few config changes) than preparing PostgreSQL DB rollouts, Could not find much on the internet, so asking here.

Please let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: You can use Django migrations for data migrations too. `makemigrations --empty` and add your data migration steps...

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not know about that, I will read more about it. Thanks!